# How to forward ports for azure virtual network gateway?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, remote-desktop, azure, virtual-network

I have created Point to site vpn using azure virtual network. Right now I have

- 2 vms in vnet (with subnet ip's 10.x.x.x)
- 1 local machine connected to vnet with point to site vpn (ip 172.x.x.x)

I can rdp vm's from local machine using 10.x.x.x and local machine from vms using 172.x.x.x

My question is - Is it possible to rdp my local machine or vm's outside the network using virtual network gateway ip (using its public ip which is 13.x.x.x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to rdp my local machine or vm's outside the network
>   using virtual network gateway ip (using its public ip which is
>   13.x.x.x)?

No, it is not possible. I answer your question in [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/865884/how-to-forward-ports-for-azure-virtual-network-gateway). You could check it.